# Get installed package root path from within package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I am building an npm package which is basically an CLI tool.
It is intended to be installed **globally** and used as CLI with `dist/clj.js`, but can also be installed as a regular dependency and accessed via `dist/index.js`.

**From inside `.js` files of my package** (like `dist/cli.js` or `dist/index.js`) I want to get an absolute path to the root of my package (where `package.json` is located).

I know this can be done with `__dirname` but for different files in my project it require different actions:

```js
// dist/cli.js
console.log(require('path').join(__dirname, '..'));

// dist/a/b/c/foo.js
console.log(require('path').join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', '..'));
```

Is there a better way to get the root of both globally or locally installed package from any `.js` file inside this package regardless of the folder this package is used in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work from any file within package:

```js
const path = require('path');

let packageRootPath = path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), '..');
```

`..` in the end needed to jump from `src`/`dist` to the root since all my `js` files are located in `src`/`dist` forders.